# Creating dropdown (Accordion) with AngularJS instead of jQuery for sidebar menu

Tags: jquery, angularjs

So i have a sidebar from a template which use jquery to create a dropdown. But i'm learning about angularjs and i think there should be a AngularJS solution for this. I keep on struggling with this. But i'm sure there must be a solution for this in the almighty angular.

```
<li ng-class=""><a href="" title="Components" ripple=""><em class="sidebar-item-icon icon-box"></em><em class="sidebar-item-caret fa pull-right fa-angle-right"></em><span translate="sidebar.nav.component.COMPONENTS">Components</span></a>
    <ul class="nav sidebar-subnav">
        <li>
            <a><em class="sidebar-item-icon fa fa-angle-right"></em>Components</a>
        </li>
        <li class="sidebar-subnav-header">
            <a><em class="sidebar-item-icon fa fa-angle-right"></em>Components</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="ui.buttons.html" title="Buttons" data-ripple=""><em class="sidebar-item-icon"></em><span>Buttons</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="ui.panels.html" title="Panels" data-ripple=""><em class="sidebar-item-icon"></em><span>Panels</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <hr>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="ui.nestable.html" title="Nestable" data-ripple=""><em class="sidebar-item-icon"></em><span>Nestable</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="ui.sortable.html" title="Sortable" data-ripple=""><em class="sidebar-item-icon"></em><span>Sortable</span></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

An example of how it works with jQuery :

[image]

A possible angularjs solution with ui-bootstrap accordion could be something like this plunker example : http://plnkr.co/edit/ToGJCbFOEmD46XDHLtt1?p=preview

But then i have 2 new problems.

How make Sub-Item behave like a link.

And then the li,ul style does not apply anymore.

Comment: Yes there is support for dropdowns. See [Angular Select](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select). Bootstrap support you find [here](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/dropdown) Do you have any more detailed questions ?

Comment: What is the specific problem? There is no jQuery shown here

Comment: When i use for example  the  <!-- Split button --> from angular-bootstrap once clicked the dropdown button it closes. But it think it should be more like the Accordion. But i want to use the css provide from the template.

Answer (score 0):

Please visit [Angularjs Bootstrap UI Dropdown](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/dropdown), this will solve you query.

Hope this helps!.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the Ionic Framework when using Angular. It's a framework which works together with Angular perfectly. You can also create easy sidemenus with it.

For more information check
[here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/preface.html).

Answer (score 0):

i think you should try [ui-bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/accordion).
they provide [accordion component](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/accordion).
you just need to add some css styling to achieve what you have in the screenshot